# How can I run a WebSocket server in NodeJS app with GAE?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, firefox, websocket

folks I'm trying run a WebSocket server in app NodeJS with GAE, but I receive the following error:

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at
>   wss://myapp.appspot.com/socket.io/?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1YWEzY2Y3ZmZmZWUzNDAwMTAwMzVlNjEiLCJpYXQiOjE1MjE2NDI2NTYsImV4cCI6MTUyMjg1MjI1Nn0._F21PRJUE2nASD8xd3KKzTKX5LX0MHrTn7V4NO9bA4g&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=3neQyUeTA6njdFULAAAI.

How can I solve it? Is possible run websocket on GAE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, GAE does [not support WebSockets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating#websockets). You can use [Compute Engine or Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/real-time-gaming-with-node-js-websocket) in order to run your application. See feature request for a Web Sockets API [here](https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/35886348)